# SQL query to maximize storage capacity in a warehouse for prime and non-prime items based on square footage

Tags: sql, database, square

Suppose you have been employed as the Data analyst for Amazon. Amazon wants to maximize the number of items it can stock in a 500,000 square feet warehouse. It wants to stock as many prime items as possible, and afterwards use the remaining square footage to stock the most of non-prime items.
As their data analyst, you have been tasked to write a query to find the number of prime and non-prime items that can be stored in the 500,000 square feet warehouse. Output the item type with prime_eligible followed by not_prime and the maximum number of items that can be stocked. For this task, you can assume the following.

1. Prime and non-prime items must be stored in equal amounts, regardless of their sizes or square footage. This means that prime items will be stored separately from non-prime items in their respective containers, but within each container, all items must be in the same amount.
2. Non-prime items must always be available in stock to meet customers demand, so the non-prime item count should never be zero.
3. Item count should be whole numbers (Integers).

Data Dictionary for table INVENTORY

| Column Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| item_id | integer |
| item_type | string |
| item_category | string |
| square_footage | decimal |

Table Input:

| item_id | item_type | item_category | square_footage |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1374 | prime_eligible | mini refrigerator | 68.00 |
| 4245 | not_prime | standing lamp | 26.40 |
| 2452 | prime_eligible | television | 85.00 |
| 3255 | not_prime | side table | 22.60 |
| 1672 | prime_eligible | laptop | 8.50 |

Expected Table Output:

| item_type | item_count |
| --- | --- |
| prime_eligible | 9285 |
| not_prime | 6 |

Tried:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        item_type,
        CASE
            WHEN item_type = 'prime_eligible' THEN 'prime'
            ELSE 'not_prime'
        END AS category,
        SUM(square_footage) AS total_square_footage
    FROM
        INVENTORY
    GROUP BY
        item_type
)
SELECT
    category AS item_type,
    FLOOR(500000 / 2 / MIN(total_square_footage)) AS item_count
FROM
    cte
GROUP BY
    category;
```

OUTPUT was

| item_type | item_count |
| --- | --- |
| not_prime | 5102 |
| prime | 1547 |

Comment: The requirements don't appear to make sense, and in some places are logically inconsistent, so your question is unanswerable. It mentions containers holding multiple items but we have no information about containers, their size/capacity, etc. In one place it says prime items take priority and in another it says there need to be equal number of prime and non-prime items

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to calculate prime first and then calculate non-prime with the remainder.

Write a couple more CTE's to calculate them separately then union the results.

In your formula, you're effectively giving the item with the least square footage under prime and non-prime equal floor space.  This cannot be the case if your expected output for prime is 9K+.  Based on the expected output, you're instead maximizing the square footage utilized by prime.